# jQuery horizontal sortable and resizable makes elements jump up when sorting

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable, resizable

I'm using jQuery to create a set of horizontally sortable elements that are also resizable with a right-side (east) handle. The problem is that after resizing an element, when I move its horizontal position, during the move the element jumps to the top of the page.

HTML

```
<div id="spacer"></div>
<div id="box">
    <div id="list">
        <div class="resize">ONE</div>
        <div class="resize">TWO</div>
        <div class="resize">THREE</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
$(function() {
    $('#list').disableSelection().sortable({
        scroll: true,
        placeholder: 'placeholder',
        containment:'parent',
        axis: 'x'
    });
    $('.resize').resizable({
            handles: 'e'
         });
});
```

CSS

```
#spacer {height: 100px}
#box {
    height: 40px;
    width: 500px;
    float: left;
}

#list {
    background-color:blue;
    white-space:nowrap;
    overflow-x:scroll;
    overflow-y:hidden;
}
.resize {
    background-color:darkgray;
    height:40px;
    width:100px;
    cursor:move;
    display:inline-block;
}
.placeholder {
    display:inline-block;
    height: 1px !important;
}


.ui-resizable-handle {
 height:15px;  
 width: 20px; 
    background-color:red;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

What am I doing wrong? jsFiddle is [here](http://bit.ly/UBZfeR).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

remove "axis:x" from your code 
change your jquery part as follows..

```
$(function () {
    $('#list').sortable({
        scroll: true,
        placeholder: 'placeholder',
        containment: 'parent',
        //axis: 'x'
    });
    $('#list').disableSelection();
    $('.resize').resizable({
        handles: 'e'
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If value for axis is defined, the items can be dragged only horizontally or vertically. Possible values: "x", "y". I am not 100 % sure but in your case its conflicting with the resizing an element.

Either Remove the axis or try

```
axis: 'xy'
```